# angularjs forms delete empty objects while submitting

Tags: forms, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `contact Form` in my App. I am adding `email field dynamically` when user clicks on `add Email button`. if user may or may not enter the value after email field generated when he clicks on add Email button.

If user not enter the value of Email and he clicks on submit, the angularjs sending data as `emails[{"key":"Work","value":"user@domine.com"},{"key":"","value":""}]` to server.

How to remove these type of empty objects `(like {"key":"","value":""})` while submitting the form to server.

Comment: just edit your object before sending and delete items with no value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before send check if if email.value is "" and remove it from array [there jsbin](http://jsbin.com/waxenusa/1/edit) :

```
$scope.send = function() {

    angular.forEach($scope.emails, function(email, index){

     if(email.value ===""){
       $scope.emails.splice(index, 1);

     } 

    });
```

Comment: I have added multiple empty values but its deleting last value and coming out of loop. why??

Comment: or this solution if you don't want create extra array http://jsbin.com/waxenusa/10/edit